# How much is 4.181,203,352,191,774,5e+33?

Tags: notation

I am trying to figure out how many possible combinations a 17 character password has. Using [elPassword](https://projects.lambry.com/elpassword/), I got an answer of `4.181,203,352,191,774,5e+33`, but I have no idea what that means. How much is that?

(Also, I have no idea what tags this fits under, but saw that the `exponential-function` tag was also known as `e`, so if you have any suggestions, please let me know)

Comment: I've changed your 'exponential function' tag to a 'notation' tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you allow $95$ characters, for
$$ 95^{17}=4\,181\,203\,352\,191\,774\,128\,676\,605\,224\,609\,375$$

Answer (score 4):

The `e+33` means $\times 10^{33}$, so this number has a 4 at the front and is followed by 33 more digits, 16 of which you know. The fancy name for $10^{33}$ is a 'decillion', so your number is approximately four decillion.

Comment: So would that be 4,181,203,352,191,774,500,000,000,000,000,000?

Comment: @Sam: Yes.$~~~$

Comment: Not quite. Those trailing $0$'s aren't right. There are significant digits there, but the website does not have room for them. @HagenvoEitzen ;s answer tells you they are 4181203352191774128676605224609375 . You could find them with Wolfram Alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=95%5E17